# Position absolute in pseudo element of blockquote

Tags: html, css, sass

I've been playing with some blockquote styling using :before and :after to insert some nice quotation marks behind the quote. However, the absolute position of the pseudo elements doesn't seem to be respected. Any pointers are much appreciated.

See: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/hylEn

Here's the SCSS I've using:

```
$secondarycolor: #c0392b;
$silver: #bdc3c7;

blockquote {
    font-size: 2.5em;
    border-left: 10px solid $secondarycolor;
    margin-left: 30px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    position: relative;

    &:before {
        content: "\201C ";
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 15px;
        font-size: 5em;
        color: $silver;
        z-index: -1;
    }

    &:after {
        content: "\201D";
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 0;
        font-size: 5em;
        color: $silver;
        z-index: -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Give the pseudo elements a `background-color`, and then look at the positioning again. For example [demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Kdgts).

Comment: AFAIK, the `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements exist outside of their parent (hence "before" rather than "first"). What happens if you wrap `blockquote` in another wrapper and give that wrapper relative-positioning?

Comment: @Dai: they're positioned relative to the `blockquote`, since that element is the first non-`display: static` element (as with other child elements with `position: absolute`) in its ancestry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The :before is missing `position: absolute` in your demo.  On the :after, you're just failing to account for the increased line-height from increasing the font-size on the quotes.  You'll need to use a negative bottom value to correct this.

```
&:after {
    content: "\201D";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -.65em;
    right: 0;
    font-size: 5em;
    color: $silver;
    z-index: -1;
}
```